# I click on the button "delete account" and it´s not working, what might be the problem based on the code below?

Tags: angular-material

```
async DeleteCompanyDialog() {
```

The `async` keyword indicates that this function is asynchronous, meaning that it can return a promise. This allows the function to wait for the `deleteUser()` operation to complete before continuing.

```
    this.saving = true;
```

This line sets the `saving` property to `true`, which indicates that the application is currently saving data. This can be used to disable certain UI elements or display a loading indicator.

```
    try {
      const deletedUser = await this.associateService.deleteUser(this.data.email);
```

This line calls the `deleteUser()` method on the `associateService` service. The `deleteUser()` method takes the email address of the company as input and returns a promise that resolves to a `deletedUser` object. The `await` keyword tells the function to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing.

```
      if (deletedUser && deletedUser?.data?.length > 0) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CompanyListDialogComponent, {
          data: deletedUser.data,
          disableClose: true
        });
      }
```

This `if` statement checks if the `deletedUser` object is not null and if the `data` property of the `deletedUser` object has a length greater than zero. If both of these conditions are met, then the function opens a `CompanyListDialogComponent` dialog box. The dialog box is disabled, so that the user cannot close it until they have selected a company from the list.

```
      else if (deletedUser && deletedUser?.data?.length == 0) {
        const dialogData: ResultDialogData = {
          success: true,
          text: 'settings.dialog.account-deleted',
          timeout: 3000
        };
        const resultDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ResultDialogComponent, {
          data: dialogData,
          disableClose: true
        });

        resultDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
          this.dialog.closeAll();
          this.logout();
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
    }finally {
      this.saving = false;
    }
  }
```